# How to return Highcharts ID, once it has been render?

Tags: highcharts, fancybox

I have a very simple question, which I can't find a solution.

when I use the click event; I log this.id, which return undefined when I am on a rendered HighCharts.

Why is that? How can I actually get the elementID where the chart is, so I can use functions that call that element? The chart is rendered on a div class, which is used for all the charts on my page (each with different ID obviously).

Event.target returns me a rect, which I can use to a certain extent, with document.mouseup, but I would like to learn how you actually identify the chart, fi I want to access it

For example, I would like to use fancybox, but it require an ID to work

```
$("#ID").fancybox();
```

EDIT:

I am able to open the chart using the href parameter, where I render the chart; but still; I have no clue how to identify programmatically a chart, once is rendered, in the click event.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming you are using the [chart click event](http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#chart.events.click) and you want the original div container:

```
chart: {
    events: {
         click: function (event) {
            var myDiv = this.container.parentElement;
         }
    }
},
```

This will return the element.

Comment: Thanks Mark, works nicely! But this will return just the DIV id; I need the chart ID, so I can change the properties of it after that I load it, when I click on it. Is there another parameter to collect that info? Thanks!

Comment: In the Highcharts.charts[] array you have all your charts. By chartID you mean a what? becuase unique value for each chart is div id.

Comment: @newbiez, I don't understand.  The `this` in the click funtion is the chart object documented here: http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#Chart.  If you need to modify the chart, use that.

Comment: Let me rephrase: I get the DIV ID, but I can't use that when I pass parameters to change the title, or the content of the chart, right? So I am looking for what identify uniquely a Highchart object. If that is the div ID, then it is fine...I am trying to understand how things fits here :)

Comment: Got it Mark, so the whole change of parameters has to be done in the click event basically. I will pass a function to click, just to keep things clean. Thanks again.